# Splitview with multiple detail views using storyboarding. Seen an example/tutorial?

Tags: uisplitviewcontroller, storyboard, detailsview

I'm trying to track down an example like Apple's MultipleDetailViews sample for UISplitViewController, but using storyboards. Their sample code provides functionality similar to what I'm after, I'm just having trouble getting it to work in my app that uses storyboards. It's driving me nuts!

Anyone seen an example/tutorial?

This is Apple's non storyboard version:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MultipleDetailViews/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to read this article:
[Science At Hand - Adventures in UISplitViewController](http://www.scienceathand.com/idevblogaday/adventures-in-uisplitviewcontroller-2/)

I found it very interesting.

Update:
Link is dead, [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20160414084950/http://www.scienceathand.com/idevblogaday/adventures-in-uisplitviewcontroller-2/) is link from archive.org

Comment: You might want to describe what was interesting, or what is described on that page, so someone reading your answer has a reason to try visiting the link.

Comment: Thanks for this! It is an interesting article. I ended up with a solution that combined multiple XIBs and the storyboard. Possibly not the best solution but seems to be working well.

Comment: You also can do it some easier, than in this article. You can use existing manual, link you posted. But instead of using "initWithNibName" use "self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"New detail view Identifier"]; It's only one change you need to do with Apple's example

Comment: What I wasn't sure about from the article is how to make it work without the TabView. I am trying to track down exactly the same as the OP.

Comment: Link you provided is dead...it's better to add some important code with answer, not just a link@igofed

Comment: Link is dead. It's usually a good idea to pull out the relevant bits from a resource so that the answer doesn't become useless if the link ceases to exist.

Answer (score 6):

Although this is an old thread, I've created a Storyboard and ARC-enabled version of Apple's MultipleDetailViews sample code, as per the OP's original request: [public git repo](https://github.com/hillmark/MultipleDetailViews)

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for something similar for Swift, but didn't find anything. After trying a few times and reading some blog posts and documentation, I could do it myself. Here is my [complete working code](https://github.com/palewar/Swift-Samples/tree/master/MultipleDetailViews). Also this is Universal project which uses Adaptive segues and works well for both iPhone and iPad.

Comment: Hi your code works like charm, I have a question: How do I change the barbuttonitem text so it displays the title of the viewcontroller. Now it is always "Master". I would like to have it like 'Notes' app of Apple :) where the title is always "Notes" and not "Folders". Thank You!!!

Comment: @Sanandrea 'Master' as backbutton item appears only in iPad Portrait mode, I guess. It's title of first navigation controller, which I have set as 'Master' in storyboard.

Comment: Yes, in the meantime I found it. I always get confused with navigation titles, as the two master view controllers have their own but also the navigation controller that hosts them :). Thanks