# Using Storyboard, UISplitViewController and multiple detail views (MultipleDetailViews with storyboard)

Tags: ios5, uistoryboard

All,

It's not this: [Science At Hand - Adventures in UISplitViewController](http://www.scienceathand.com/idevblogaday/adventures-in-uisplitviewcontroller-2/).  That really goes from the UITabBarController rather than the cells in the Master.

Let's say I want to create a SplitViewController.  On the left side I have different types of cells in the same list (It's not going on Apple Store, so I don't care if it's Apple iOk or not).  For each of the different cell types I want to have a different DetailView controller.  Cell Type A shows DetailView A, Cell Type B shows DetailView B.

1. How do I update the SplitViewController subviews to shift detailviews?
2. Can I just put the navigation controller under the detail and then add viewControllers to that?  Using the get based on seque name or get view from storyboard?
3. Some other, really obvious way that I'm just missing.

For bonus points, I would like a way to detect that I'm leaving one detailview (for saving) and moving to a different detailview (A different cell type button was pressed)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Splitview with multiple detail views using storyboarding. Seen an example/tutorial?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7993168/splitview-with-multiple-detail-views-using-storyboarding-seen-an-example-tutori)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out it was simple.

If you do the obvious (who would have thought?) it works just fine.  I created my different cellviews.  Each cell view has details link that I just linked to a series of view controllers.  I just had to change the seque so that it was a replace and it put the view into the detail view.

Comment: Yo, any chance of that code (even pseudo) to become available? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm make this sample in GitHub

https://github.com/AlfonsoMoreno/MultipleDetailView

MasterViewController is UITableViewController

FirstDetailViewController is UIViewController
SecondDetailViewController is UITableViewController

You can add more views!!!

Please watch MultipleDetailViewManager class!!!