# UISplitViewController - Static master table view and multiple detail view controller

Tags: objective-c, ipad, cocoa-touch, storyboard, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm trying to create an app which will have a similar interface to iOS's Settings app and I'm a bit lost on how to proceed.

Basically, I plan to make the master view a static table view. And each of the rows in that static table view has their own detail view controller.

I currently made my master static table view via storyboard. How would I make each of the row, when tapped, show their respective detail view controllers on the detail view? I'd like to know what's the best way of proceeding in this situation.

I've look through the net for tutorials but only saw dynamic master table view with only 1 detail view controller tutorials. And they used delegates to hook up the Left and Right view controllers. But as for me, I do not have a model object as I'm using a static table view.

I know how to do this programmatically (hooking up the left and right views), but I plan to use storyboards for this since I have multiple static table views that are the detail views of the rows in my master table view. I do not know how to do it with storyboards.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UISplitViewController - Multiple Detail View Controllers via storyboard segues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21391073/uisplitviewcontroller-multiple-detail-view-controllers-via-storyboard-segues)

Answer (score 12):

In Xcode 6, look into the "Show Detail" segue. You can drag it from the master view controller to other detail views and swap them out by calling this segue from master.

[Here's a quick example of this.](https://github.com/dstarsboy/TMMultiDetailSplitView)

Answer (score 0):

This is old code, but I was able to implement it in an iOS 6 project last year and it seems to work fine in iOS 7 (we are updating the project now, but initial tests show it working).

Basically it gives a fully documented approach to implementing multiple detail views in a split view controller using Interface Builder:

http://www.scienceathand.com/idevblogaday/adventures-in-uisplitviewcontroller-2/

Comment: Link is broken, I found this which I think is the same; http://web.archive.org/web/20160414084950/http://www.scienceathand.com/idevblogaday/adventures-in-uisplitviewcontroller-2/

Comment: Down voted as the link is broken, and the archive.org link does not work currently either.